# C++ Add real world time to timestamp on charts

Tags: c++, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

I'm making a little ESP8266 project for myself, in which I want to display the Temperature and Humidity of an DHT11 sensor on a website. The code I have now works perfectly, but the timestamps at the charts are kinda weird. I want these timestamps to be the real time of Amsterdam when the data is uploaded to the charts. Is there anyone with any experience to do this? Let me know! Thanks in advance!

```
#include <DHT.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

#define DHTTYPE DHT11
#define DHTPIN 2
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
ESP8266WebServer server(80);
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.begin("SSID", "Password");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");
  
  dht.begin();
  
  server.on("/", []() {
    String html = "<html><body>";
    html += "<style> body{text-align:center; font-family:sans-serif;}#temp,#hum{color:red;}h1{font-size:75px;}.top{margin-top:50px;}</style>";
    html += "<h1 class='top'>Temperatuur: <span id='temp'>Loading...</span> *C</h1>";
    html += "<h1>Luchtvochtigheid <span id='hum'>Loading...</span> %</h1>";
    html += "<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js'></script>";
    html += "<canvas id='tempChart'></canvas>";
    html += "<canvas id='humChart' style='margin-top:50px;'></canvas>";
    html += "<script>setInterval(function(){fetch('/temp-hum').then(res=>res.text()).then(tempHum=>{let [temp, hum] = tempHum.split(','); document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML=temp; document.getElementById('hum').innerHTML=hum});fetch('/getTempData').then(res => res.json()).then(data => {tempChart.data.labels.push(data.time); tempChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(data.temp); tempChart.update()});fetch('/getHumData').then(res => res.json()).then(data => {humChart.data.labels.push(data.time); humChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(data.hum); humChart.update()})}, 10000);</script>";
    html += "<script>var tempCtx = document.getElementById('tempChart').getContext('2d');var tempChart = new Chart(tempCtx, {type: 'line',data: { labels: [],datasets: [{label: 'Temperature',data: [],borderColor: 'red',fill: false}]},options: {scales: {yAxes: [{scaleLabel: {display: true,labelString: 'Temperature (°C)'}}],xAxes: [{scaleLabel: {display: true,labelString: 'Time'}}]},title: {display: true,text: 'Temperature over time'},legend: {display: true }}});var humCtx = document.getElementById('humChart').getContext('2d');var humChart = new Chart(humCtx, {type: 'line',data:{ labels: [],datasets: [{label: 'Humidity',data: [],borderColor: 'blue',fill: false}]},options: {scales: {yAxes: [{scaleLabel: {display: true,labelString: 'Humidity (%)'}}],xAxes: [{scaleLabel: {display: true,labelString: 'Time'}}]},title: {display: true,text: 'Humidity over time'},legend: {display: true }}})</script>";
    html += "</body></html>";
    server.send(200, "text/html", html);
  });

  server.on("/temp-hum", []() {
    String temp = String(dht.readTemperature());
    String hum = String(dht.readHumidity());
    String tempHum = temp + "," + hum;
    server.send(200, "text/plain", tempHum);
  });

  server.on("/getTempData", []() {
    String time = String(millis());
    String temp = String(dht.readTemperature());
    String data = "{\"time\":\""+time+"\",\"temp\":\""+temp+"\"}";
    server.send(200, "application/json", data);
  });
  
  server.on("/getHumData", []() {
    String time = String(millis());
    String hum = String(dht.readHumidity());
    String data = "{\"time\":\""+time+"\",\"hum\":\""+hum+"\"}";
    server.send(200, "application/json", data);
  });
  
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");
}

void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
}
```

Comment: `millis()` herre is **Milliseconds since ignition of the device** not the real time

Comment: I know, but I don't know how to change it to the real world time

Comment: you can't change it , you have to get it from somewhere else.

Comment: since the time of measurement is the time of display, you can use the current time in browser

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to find [unix time](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/epoch-unix-time-esp8266-nodemcu-arduino/)(time since Jan 1970), that is quite easy to convert from nanaoseconds to time in amsterdam. So converting Unix time into CET. It that's a bit too much work, and time accuracy is not extremely important. You could make a [request](http://worldtimeapi.org/) and parse it. Hope this helped a bit.

Comment: `millis()` herre is Milliseconds **since ignition** of the device nor the real time nor **the Unix epoch**

Comment: I know that millis isn't unix epoch, the post i linked shows how to sync/get it over the internet...

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to get real time clock

- Use [**NTP Client-Server**](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-nodemcu-date-time-ntp-client-server-arduino/) to get real world time
  [image: NTP Client-Server]
- (or) [**Add RTC (Real time clock) module to your ESP**](https://how2electronics.com/esp8266-ds3231-real-time-clock/)

[image: Real time clock module]